# How can I defend myself against an abusive fighter? 14 comments in 28 minutes!

Tags: support

See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73588/9215) ;  see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70698/9215) someone had posted to me ***14 posts to fight me in 28 minutes***. I want to know what is the way following the law to resolve this problem

**Please answer without waffle or prevarication**.

Comment: I don't view those comments as abusive and I doubt they were intended that way. I'm sorry they affected you so.

Comment: Any particular reason you bumped this old question now with minor edits?

Comment: @Monica  Cellio Yes,  I was trying to understand the way to avoid escalation.  I was wondering,  asking myself,... It is linked also to the recent discussion about moderators

Comment: @Monica Cellio how can I have a private discussion with you. it is not easy to address the issue in a entirely public way

Answer (score 7):

The comments that I can see on the two linked posts appear to be (properly) addressing the content rather than its author, critiquing or requesting improvements to the content. This seems to me to be an appropriate use of comments. The posts the comments apply to are long and complicated, so it seems reasonable that a user could find many points worthy of critique and address them each in a separate comment. It does not seem that the comments in question are abusively repetitive.

Assuming that the comments, individually and collectively, are justified, it shouldn't matter much how much time passed between their being posted. Communication on Stack Exchange is asynchronous.

Suggested appropriate responses to such a large collection of comments:

- If you see that the comments describe genuine room for improvement in your posts, edit the posts in question to improve them as suggested in the comments or to  remove the issues dealt with in the comments.
- If you disagree with the critiques offered in the comments, respond with your own comments, explaining where you disagree.
- If you need more information from the commenter to understand what the comments are getting at, respond with your own comments, asking for clarification.
- If you disagree with the critiques and believe that they are so off-base as to not require a response, ignore them.
- (*A priori*) Write posts as clearly and succinctly as possible. The more concepts and words in a post, the more possible hooks for critique.

In cases where [you believe] some or all of the comments are, in fact, abusive, the following modes of response are available:

- Add a comment politely asking the author to desist from the abusive behavior, e.g. "Please keep your comments focused on the content here, and refrain from trying to evaluate me as a person." I would recommend usually not going further than one comment down this road, since a long stream of comments on the topic of whether other comments are abusive or not becomes an off-topic blight on the post.
- Make a similar request in Chat, where side conversations are welcome.
- [Flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365) any and all comments that you consider to be abusive of yourself or others. If it's not self-explanatory what's wrong with the comments you're flagging, or if you're trying to bring attention to a collection of comments as a body, use the "other ..." option, and then write a sentence explaining what you're objecting to. This will bring the problematic comments to the moderators' attention.

Comment: "If you disagree with the critiques and believe that they are so off-base as to not require a response, ignore them."  But I feel that you do not explain what to do again relentlessness

Comment: I think that your post is interesting but you did miss something, perhaps have new insights or personal opinions about the role of moderators to avoid escalation

Comment: @kouty I've added material on what to do when you receive comments that you consider abusive.

Comment: I did read attentively your edit,  we need to pray that this will remain needless and not helpless